# c++ openmp with shared_pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, openmp

here is a minimal example of what bothers me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include"omp.h"

class A{
    public:
        A(){std::cout<<this<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++){
        std::shared_ptr<A> sim(std::make_shared<A>());
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++){
        std::shared_ptr<A> sim(std::make_shared<A>());
    }
}
```

If I run that code a few times I may get this kind of result :

```
0xea3308
0xea32d8
0xea3338
0x7f39f80008c8
0xea3338
0xea3338
0xea3338
0xea3338
```

What I realized is that the 4 last output have always the same number of
characters (8). But for some reason it happens (not always) that one or more of
the four first output contains more (14) characters. It looks like the use of
openmp changes the "nature" of the pointer (this is my naive understanding).
But is this behaviour normal ? Should I expect some strange behaviour ?

## EDIT

[here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/070858a7392cbec3) is a live test that shows the same problem in a slightly more complicated version of the code

Comment: a downvote 5 sec after posting ? why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is entirely reasonable, let's see what's happening.

## Serial loop

In every iteration you're getting one `A` that's being created on the heap, and one is getting destroyed. These operations are ordered like so:

1. construction
2. destruction
3. construction
4. destruction
5. ... (and so on)

Since the `A`s are being created on the heap, they go through the memory allocator. When the memory allocator gets a request for new memory as in step 3, it will (in many cases) first look at recently freed memory. It sees that the last operation was a memory free of exactly the right size (step 2), and therefore will take that chunk of memory again. This procedure will repeat in each iteration. So the serial loop will (commonly but not necessarily) give you the same address over and over again.

## Parallel loop

Now let's think about the parallel loop. Since there is no synchronization the ordering of the memory allocations and deallocations is not determined. Therefore it is possible for them to be interleaved in whatever way you can imagine. So the memory allocator will in general not be able to use the same trick as last time to always hand out the same piece of memory. An example ordering may be for example that all four `A`s get constructed before they all get destroyed - something like this:

1. construction
2. construction
3. construction
4. construction
5. destruction
6. destruction
7. destruction
8. destruction

The memory allocator will therefore have to *serve up* 4 brand new pieces of memory before it can get some back and start recycling.

The behaviour of the stack based version is slightly more deterministic, but can depend on compiler optimizations. For the serial version every time the object is created/destroyed the stack pointer is adjusted. Since there is nothing happening in between, it will keep getting created in the same location.

For the parallel version, every thread has it's own stack in a shared memory system. Therefore each thread will create it's objects in a different memory location, and no "recycling" is possible.

The behaviour you're seeing is in no way strange or for that matter guaranteed. It depends on the amount of physical cores you have, how many threads get run, how many iterations you use - generally runtime conditions.

**Bottom line**: everything is fine, you shouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: really nice answer, thx. I can now understand why in the serial version, it prints always the same thing and why in the parallel it doesn't. but this doesn't answer why the fourth cout contains 14 characters and the tree firsts only 8 (taken from my example). What is the meaning of short vs long "names" for pointer?

Comment: That would just be the location in memory. The stack is located at the top of the memory space and grows downwards. A long address would mean that the heap location was found somewhere closer to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends to your environment it is not revelant and should not be considered as strange behaviour.
Using MS VS 2015 preview, your code gives me the following (with OMP enabled) :

```
0082C3DC
0082C41C   
0082C49C                                       
0082C45C                                       
0082C41C                                       
0082C41C                                       
0082C41C                   
0082C41C
```

Comment: most of the time I get such a result, but sometimes I get the kind I showed in my question... how many times have you tried to run my code ?

Comment: Just did it 10 times I have never encountered your behaviour. What do you use ? I will try it using GCC.

Comment: I indeed get your behaviour using gcc 4.9 but I do not think it can be considered as strange behaviour. The memory address is still valid.

Comment: I think so I do not see why it would be a problem.  Let someone else confirm this :)